# flutter camera - what is the difference between CameraPreview(controller) and controller.buildPreiview()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to use camera with flutter.

I want to understand the difference between `CameraPreview(controller)` and `controller.buildPreiview()` because it behaves differently for some reason.

This is the code for the showing the preview:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isCameraInitialized
        ? Material(
            child: Stack(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    ...
                    child: _cameraController!.buildPreview()
                    // child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!)
                  ),
                  ....
                ]
            ),
        )
        : Container();
```

The result for using `_cameraController!.buildPreview()`:
[image]

This is the desired result - make the camera preview appear as full screen.

But the result for using `CameraPreview(_cameraController!)` is:
[image]

This leaves the right of the screen white and does not take the full width of the screen for some reason. I also tried to wrap it with `AspectRatio` but it didn't work.

I was wondering why those methods behave differently and if it is better to use one of them over the other?

Answer (score 1):

use this solution it will remove the right vertical banner :

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
child:CameraPreview(_cameraController),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CameraPreview(controller)` is actually calling `controller.buildPreview()` within its `build(context)` method, but wrap within an `AspectRatio` widget and set to the aspect ratio of:

1. `previewSize!.width / previewSize!.height` if the device orientation is in landscape, or
2. `1 / previewSize!.width / previewSize!.height` if it is in portrait.

where the `previewSize` is the targeting (or lower) resolution preset of the `CameraController`.

```
// camera_preview.dart (as on 23 May 2023)

class CameraPreview extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraPreview(this.controller, {super.key, this.child});

  final CameraController controller;

  final Widget? child;

  @Override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller.value.isInitialized
        ? ValueListenableBuilder<CameraValue>(
            valueListenable: controller,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Object? value, Widget? child) {
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _isLandscape()
                    ? controller.value.aspectRatio
                    : (1 / controller.value.aspectRatio),
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _wrapInRotatedBox(child: controller.buildPreview()),
                    child ?? Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            child: child,
          )
        : Container();
  }
  // ...
}
```

Refer [camera_preview.dart](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/camera/camera/lib/src/camera_preview.dart) for the complete source code.

While looking at the code of `controller.buildPreview()` below:

```
// camera_controller.dart (as on 23 May 2023)

Widget buildPreview() {
  _throwIfNotInitialized('buildPreview');
  try {
    return CameraPlatform.instance.buildPreview(_cameraId);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    throw CameraException(e.code, e.message);
  }
}
```

It is calling the `buildPreview(cameraId)` method from the `MethodChannelCamera`, an implementation of `CameraPlatform` that uses method channels, and returns a `Texture` widget:

```
// method_channel_camera.dart (as on 23 May 2023)

@override
Widget buildPreview(int cameraId) {
  return Texture(textureId: cameraId);
}
```

From [the class doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html), a `Texture` widget is

> A rectangle upon which a backend texture is mapped.
>
> Backend textures are images that can be applied (mapped) to an area of
> the Flutter view. They are created, managed, and updated using a
> platform-specific texture registry. This is typically done by a plugin
> that integrates with host platform video player, camera, or OpenGL
> APIs, or similar image sources.

So in conclusion, the main difference between the two is that the `CameraPreview(controller)` respects to the aspect ratio of the resolution preset while `controller.buildPreview()` is not and always fill up the given size constraint.

**Simple Sample**
[image]
I have built a simple sample by passing the widget of each way to the body of a `Scaffold` widget and run it on a long screen device (20:9). The result camera preview is shown above, you may notice that the remote is distorted on the preview screen created using `controller.buildPreview()` (Screen capture on the right).